# Navigation nodes of Primefaces Tree - Single Selection with buttons

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two buttons and I have to navigate through these nodes TreeNode in my tree. 
My idea is to update the SelectedNode at each iteration the user with the buttons. But the update does not work properly and the SelectedNode remains one selected with the click. How can I do this properly?

```
 myBean(){
 ...
 private TreeNode selectedNode;
 private TreeNode navigazione;

 //Getter and Setter
 .......


    public void navigate(){

    if(getSelectedNode!=null && getSelectedNode().getChildCount()>0){

        navigazione=getSelectedNode().getChildren().get(0);
        System.out.print(getNavigazione().getChildCount()+getNavigazione().getData().toString());
        setSelectedNode(navigazione);
    }
    return;

}
```

xhtml portion

```
 p:panel id="navTree" style="border:none; background:transparent; align:left"
 p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" disabled="false" ajax="true"
 actionListener="#{myBean.navigate}">/p:commandButton>
```

Note that the tags are opened and closed properly and not as here to display problems
Thanks!

Comment: Look to how the actionListener was defined. I believe they must accept an actionEvent, thus

`public void navigate(ActionEvent event){`

Comment: That won't be the case if the System.out.print() is triggered.

Comment: I solved it. My function did not update another data structure that commanded the tree. Over setSelected node had to do it on a hashmap of individual nodes created earlier